# Error Datasource Postgres with WSO2 DAS

Tags: postgresql, wso2

I am trying to change the WSO2 DAS data source from H2 to postgres.

I have configured all the database changes in master-datasource.xml, user-mgt.xml, and registry.xml

The below exception is being thrown while creating an event Table

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.rdbms.DBHandler.initializeDatabaseExecutionInfo(DBHandler.java:392)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.rdbms.DBHandler.<init>(DBHandler.java:73)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.RDBMSEventTable.init(RDBMSEventTable.java:112)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.helper.DefinitionParserHelper.addEventTable(DefinitionParserHelper.java:99)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.ExecutionPlanRuntimeBuilder.defineTable(ExecutionPlanRuntimeBuilder.java:74)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.defineTableDefinitions(ExecutionPlanParser.java:162)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.parse(ExecutionPlanParser.java:115)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.validateExecutionPlan(SiddhiManager.java:68)
        at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.validateExecutionPlan(SiddhiManager.java:74)
        at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.helper.EventProcessorHelper.validateExecutionPlan(EventProcessorHelper.java:191)
```

I try with this code:

```
@From(eventtable='rdbms', jdbc.url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pruebabg', username='postgres', password='postgres', driver.name='org.postgresql.Driver', table.name='pharming')
define table pharming (phi_id_pharming_incident long, phi_id_license int, phi_machine_user_id string, phi_date string, phi_machine_user_date string, phi_protected_site string, phi_pharming_glp string, 
                                phi_user_ip string, phi_dsb_version string, phi_os string, phi_os_version string, user_id int);
```

I try with this code too:

```
@From(eventtable='rdbms', datasource.name='WSO2_CARBON_DB', table.name='pharming_incident')
define table pharming_incident (phi_id_pharming_incident long, phi_id_license int, phi_machine_user_id string, phi_date string, phi_machine_user_date string, phi_protected_site string, phi_pharming_glp string, 
                                phi_user_ip string, phi_dsb_version string, phi_os string, phi_os_version string, user_id int);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answear.

The Event table is only tested with some databases:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Siddhi+Query+Language#SiddhiQueryLanguage-RDBMSEventTable

"RDBMS event table has been tested with the following databases: 
MySQL
H2
Oracle"

Anyway, I try updating the rdbms-table-config.xml which is there in /repository/components/plugins/siddhi-extension-event-table_3.x.x.jar a per :
 https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-extensions/event-table/src/main/resources/rdbms-table-config.xml .

```html
 </mapping>
        <mapping db='postgresql'>
            <elements>
                <element key="bool">SMALLINT</element>
    <element key="integer">INTEGER</element>
            </elements>
        </mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check following.

1. Make sure that you have run the relevant database script located at
   /dbscripts/postgresql.sql against your database.
2. Make sure the relevant database driver is placeed in
   /repository/components/lib folder.

I suspect that there is some incorrect configuration in your master-datasources.xml. If you could share your config in master-datasources.xml it would be easier to track down the exact issue. Please find the instructions(for DAS 3.0.0) on how to set up the PostgreSQL database with WSO2 DAS in this link [1]. Hope you find this information helpful.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Setting+up+PostgreSQL

Comment: A few other things you can check :-
1. Make sure that you have run the relevant database script located at <PRODUCT_HOME>/dbscripts/postgresql.sql against your database.
2. Make sure the relevant database driver is placeed in <PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/components/lib folder.